# Anorm - generic insert

Tags: scala, anorm

Is there a way to use Anorm like a regular ORM? I'd like to have a method that just inserts an element provided.

```
  def insert[T](element: T)(implicit connection: Connection) = {
    element.insert(connection)
  }
```

I can definitely implement it by myself, but feels like I'm re-implementing an ORM... Old anorm version had this [Magic[T]](https://www.playframework.com/modules/scala-0.9.1/anorm#AddingsomeMagicT) but I can't see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://playframework.github.io/anorm) clearly states that Anorm is not an ORM (and will never be).

As [indicated](https://playframework.github.io/anorm/#custom-parameter-conversions), to insert or update a `T` value, an instance of the `ToStatement` typeclass must be provided.

Some [macros are provided](https://playframework.github.io/anorm/#generated-parameter-conversions) to automatically materialize such instance.

```
import anorm.{ Macro, SQL, ToParameterList }
import anorm.NamedParameter

case class Bar(v: Int)

val bar1 = Bar(1)

// Convert all supported properties as parameters
val toParams1: ToParameterList[Bar] = Macro.toParameters[Bar]

val params1: List[NamedParameter] = toParams1(bar1)
// --> List(NamedParameter(v,ParameterValue(1)))

val names1: List[String] = params1.map(_.name)
// --> List(v)

val placeholders = names1.map { n => s"{$n}" } mkString ", "
// --> "{v}"

val generatedStmt = s"""INSERT INTO bar(${names1 mkString ", "}) VALUES ($placeholders)"""
val generatedSql1 = SQL(generatedStmt).on(params1: _*)
```